# Replace tag name with string

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Lets say I had some HTML code, such as:

```
"Hello, my <strong>name</strong> is Nanoo."
```

How could I replace the `<strong>` tag with a string?

For example:

```
"Hello, my **name** is Nanoo."
```

(Replaces the `<strong>` tag with `**`)

I could probably use the `replace()` function, however I want to do this efficiently.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [parentNode.replaceChild(newChild, oldChild);](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild).

```js
// on DOMContentLoaded 
document.querySelectorAll('strong').forEach(function(ele) { // for each strong tag
    var newTag = document.createTextNode('**' + ele.textContent + '**');
    ele.parentNode.replaceChild(newTag, ele);
})
```

```html
<p>Hello, my <strong>name</strong> is Nanoo.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression. (`(.+?)` is used to capture the contents of the strong tag, so we can use `$1` in the replacement to substitute the captured group.)

However, [don't use regexps to really parse HTML.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/51685)

```
>>> s = "Hello, my <strong>name</strong> is Nanoo.";
>>> s.replace(/<strong>(.+?)<\/strong>/g, '**$1**');
"Hello, my **name** is Nanoo."
```